# Interchange String with Date in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running the below query.  I would like to make this query more dynamic, however, so I would like to use the 2nd query instead.

```
SELECT  X
FROM    Y
WHERE   Z
and  file_created_date  = '12/18/2016'


SELECT  X
FROM    Y
WHERE   Z
and  file_created_date  = SELECT date(GETDATE()-2)
```

The 2nd query returns an error around the Select of

```
SELECT date(GETDATE()-2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres supports interval offsets for dates:

```
where Z and
      file_created_date = current_date - interval '2 day'
```

If `file_created_date` also has a time component, then you should take that into account:

```
where Z and
      file_created_date > current_date - interval '3 day' and
      file_created_date <= current_date - interval '2 day'
```

Answer (score 1):

`GETDATE()` isn't available in postgres. You can however use `current_date` i.e.

`... and file_created_date = current_date - 2`